# Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

Building a scheduling system for college tutors. I've written a LINQ query that runs on a button click and I want to return the available slots in a gridview. Because the query returns an anonymous type the databind is throwing the error in the title. I've hunted around for a fix on here but there's nothing where the query is within a control (button here) so I'm not sure how to make the change.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sessions] (
[sessionID]              INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[create_date]            DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[last_update_date]       DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[tutorCWID]              INT           NOT NULL,
[semesterID]             INT           NOT NULL,
[session_date]           DATE          NOT NULL,
[session_start_time]     TIME (7)      NOT NULL,
[session_end_time]       NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
[session_bookings]       INT           NOT NULL,
[session_group_size]     INT           NOT NULL,
[session_student_report] VARCHAR (500) NULL,
[session_tutor_report]   VARCHAR (500) NULL,
[session_documents]      VARCHAR (100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Session] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([sessionID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Session_UserProfileTutor] FOREIGN KEY ([tutorCWID])            REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfiles] ([userCWID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Session_Semester] FOREIGN KEY ([semesterID]) REFERENCES     [dbo].[Semesters] ([semesterID]));

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfiles] (
[userCWID]     INT           NOT NULL,
[first_name]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[last_name]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[email]        VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[phone_mobile] NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
[phone_work]   NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
[status]       NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
[password]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[user_typeID]  INT           NOT NULL,
[ImareUrl]     VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tutor] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userCWID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfile_UserType] FOREIGN KEY ([user_typeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserTypes] ([user_typeID]));

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfiles_Courses] (
[tutorCWID] INT            NOT NULL,
[courseID]  VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
[note]      NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserProfiles_Courses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([tutorCWID] ASC, [courseID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfiles_Courses_Courses] FOREIGN KEY ([courseID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Courses] ([courseID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfiles_Courses_UserProfiles] FOREIGN KEY ([tutorCWID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfiles] ([userCWID]));
```

ASP.NET Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Students_StudentSelectSession : System.Web.UI.Page
{

string _StdSessCourse = "";
DateTime _StdSessDate = DateTime.Now;
string _semester = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnStdSessSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _StdSessCourse = ddlStdSessCourse.SelectedValue;
    _StdSessDate = calStdSessDate.SelectedDate;


    using (ISDS411_FinalProjectDB_5Entities stdSessEntity = new ISDS411_FinalProjectDB_5Entities())
    {
        var stdSessAvailable = (from s in stdSessEntity.Sessions
                                join up in stdSessEntity.UserProfiles on s.tutorCWID equals up.userCWID
                                join uc in stdSessEntity.UserProfiles_Courses on up.userCWID equals uc.tutorCWID
                                where uc.courseID == _StdSessCourse && s.session_date == _StdSessDate
                                orderby s.session_date
                                select new
                                {
                                    up.first_name,
                                    up.last_name,
                                    s.session_start_time,
                                    s.session_end_time,
                                    s.session_group_size,
                                    s.session_bookings,
                                }).FirstOrDefault();

        gvStdSessAvailable.DataSource = stdSessAvailable;
        gvStdSessAvailable.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the gridview:

```
<%@ Page Title="Student - Select Tutoring Session" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Students/StudentMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StudentSelectSession.aspx.cs" Inherits="Students_StudentSelectSession" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent" Runat="Server">
<h1>Select a session</h1>
<p>Use the controls below to select a tutoring session:
    <ol>
        <li>Select the course you want to be tutored in from the dropdown menu.</li>
        <li>Select the date that you are looking for a tutoring session on.</li>
        <li>Click the "Search" button.</li>
    </ol>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStdSessCourse" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="courseID" DataValueField="courseID"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ISDS411_FinalProjectDB_5ConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [courseID] FROM [Courses]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Calendar ID="calStdSessDate" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnStdSessSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnStdSessSearch_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvStdSessAvailable" runat="server" DataKeyNames="sessionID" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"></asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><a href="~/Students/StudentHome.aspx" runat="server">Go back to Student Homepage</a></p>
```

I guess this needs to something other than an anonymous type but not sure how to put it together. Alternatively, I could not use a grid view but I wanted to take advantage of the "select" feature to allow students to select the tutoring session they want.

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur. Made changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try change: `.FirstOrDefault();` to `.AsEnumerable();`

"I guess this needs to something other than an anonymous type but not sure how to put it together"
Just create a new class with properties and use it like this:

```
var stdSessAvailable = (from s in stdSessEntity.Sessions
                            join up in stdSessEntity.UserProfiles on s.tutorCWID equals up.userCWID
                            join uc in stdSessEntity.UserProfiles_Courses on up.userCWID equals uc.tutorCWID
                            where uc.courseID == _StdSessCourse && s.session_date == _StdSessDate
                            orderby s.session_date
                            select new SessAvailable
                            {
                               FirstName = up.first_name,
                               LastName = up.last_name,
                               SessionStarTime = s.session_start_time,
                               SessionEndTime = s.session_end_time,
                               SessionGroupSize = s.session_group_size,
                               SessionBookings = s.session_bookings,
                            }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Thank you @hekta! I get a type or namespace cannot be found for SessAvailable. Any ideas? Edit: I created a new class for SessAvailable using the little icon next to it. So the class is created but now "FirstName, LastName"... etc. are highlighted saying "SessAvailable" does not contain a definition for"X". How do I add these? Do I generate property stubs? Property fields?

Comment: I created a "SessAvailable" class which was added in the app_code folder. I put the headers in as follows:

     public class SessAvailable
    {
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public TimeSpan SessionStartTime;
    public string SessionEndTime;
    public int SessionGroupSize;
    public int SessionBookings;
    }

I get this error now:

"The data source for GridView with id 'gvStdSessAvailable' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content."

Comment: No problem Rob P. Are You creating these properties as Auto-Implemented Properties ?

Comment: Hi @hekta. I seem to have found a way to make it bind to the grid. All I had to do was remove ".FirstOrDefault()" and I could put ".ToList()" after my variable before I bound it. I read somewhere that I had to use first or default to make it behind, though it seemed counter-intuitive as I was returning multiple records/values. Seems I was right. No Enumerable needed.  Thanks for the help all the same, greatly appreciated.